# POST values Symfony request object

Tags: php, symfony

this is a newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. 
In a controller in Symfony3.4. Trying to get the response from my POST form with Symfony

In the controller I have:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Message/Board/post", name="Messagepost")
 */
    public function PostMeg()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $message = new message($request->request->get("txtName"));
        $message->setMes($request->request->get("txtMes"));
        $entityManager->persist($message);
        $entityManager->flush();  
        return $this->redirect('/app_dev.php/Message/Board/page=1');
    }
```

And I have error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO message_board
>   (name, mes, updatetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null,
>   "2019-09-16 11:50:48"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name'
>   cannot be null

this is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace MegBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="message_board")
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MegBundle\Entity\message")
 **/

class message
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string")
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mes",type="string")
     */
    private $mes;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatetime",type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatetime;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->updatetime = new \datetime();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getMes()
    {
        return $this->mes;
    }

    public function getUpdateTime()
    {
        return $this->updatetime;
    }

    public function setMes($mes)
    {
        $this->mes = $mes;
    }
}
```

and my form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    暱稱*：<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" value="<?= $UserN ?>" required/><br>
    <br>
    留言*：<input type="textarea" size="50px" height="50px" name="txtMes" id="txtMes" value="<?= $UserM ?>"/><br>
    <br>
    <div style="display:<?= $hid2 ?>"><input type="submit" name="btnOK" id="btnOK" value="送出留言" onclick="location.href='/app_dev.php/Message/Board/post'"/></div><br>
    <div style="display:<?= $hid2 ?>"><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="重填留言" /></div><br>
    <div style="display:<?= $hid ?>"><input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="修改留言" onclick="location.href='/app_dev.php/Message/Board/update'"/></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: technically, your `message` object might have neither `name´ nor `mes`, since `name` can't be empty, the error is thrown. However, my statement might be irrelevant, if you don't store the `message` object in the `message_board` table. since you call your entity class `message`, it makes me think you don't follow the normal doctrine/symfony naming convention, also you don't have an `id` column. which also is quite unusual. in any case, if my comment doesn't already solve your problem, provide your entity and the form please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your form is not submitting the data `onclick="location.href='/app_dev.php/Message/Board/post'"` I think this is sending a GET request before the form submits the POST request (thus the values are `NULL`).

I would recommend changing the `onclick`property of your submit buttons to call a javascript function that either:
**A:** collects the form data and makes an AJAX POST request to appropriate URL
OR
**B:** fills the form's `action` property with the correct URL and then allows the form to submit naturally.